# How do I properly set the delegate property? (swift)

Tags: swift, delegates

I'm trying to implement SQLClient into an existing iOS app. The app is a barcode reader that fires off an INSERT to a DB over the LAN. SQLClient's delegate property must be set to an NSObject for error handling but I'm having trouble setting it. **My implementation troubles are in the last method, `found`.**

Firstly, Xcode wanted me to downcast to a more specific type. After taking Xcode's advice and casting `client as Anyobject` I then get `Ambiguous use of delegate`.

So, in short, I need help setting SQLClient's delegate property so I can fire off my insert. I'm willing to learn if y'all can recommend a resource or offer guidance.

SQLClient --> https://github.com/martinrybak/SQLClient

```
//
//  QRScannerController.swift
//  QRCodeReader
//
//  Created by Simon Ng on 13/10/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 AppCoda. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class QRScannerController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var messageLabel:UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var topbar: UIView!

    var captureSession:AVCaptureSession?
    var videoPreviewLayer:AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var qrCodeFrameView:UIView?

    let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeAztecCode,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
                        AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDevice class to initialize a device object and provide the video as the media type parameter.
        let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

        do {
            // Get an instance of the AVCaptureDeviceInput class using the previous device object.
            let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

            // Initialize the captureSession object.
            captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

            // Set the input device on the capture session.
            captureSession?.addInput(input)

            // Initialize a AVCaptureMetadataOutput object and set it as the output device to the capture session.
            let captureMetadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()
            captureSession?.addOutput(captureMetadataOutput)

            // Set delegate and use the default dispatch queue to execute the call back
            captureMetadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            captureMetadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = supportedCodeTypes

            // Initialize the video preview layer and add it as a sublayer to the viewPreview view's layer.
            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
            videoPreviewLayer?.frame = view.layer.bounds
            view.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

            // Start video capture.
            captureSession?.startRunning()

            // Move the message label and top bar to the front
            view.bringSubview(toFront: messageLabel)
            view.bringSubview(toFront: topbar)

            // Initialize QR Code Frame to highlight the QR code
            qrCodeFrameView = UIView()

            if let qrCodeFrameView = qrCodeFrameView {
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
                qrCodeFrameView.layer.borderWidth = 2
                view.addSubview(qrCodeFrameView)
                view.bringSubview(toFront: qrCodeFrameView)
            }

        } catch {
            // If any error occurs, simply print it out and don't continue any more.
            print(error)
            return
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    // MARK: - AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate Methods

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [Any]!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        captureSession?.stopRunning()
        // Check if the metadataObjects array is not nil and it contains at least one object.
        if metadataObjects == nil || metadataObjects.count == 0 {
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = CGRect.zero
            messageLabel.text = "No QR/barcode is detected"
            return
        }

        // Get the metadata object.
        let metadataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        if supportedCodeTypes.contains(metadataObj.type) {
            // If the found metadata is equal to the QR code metadata then update the status label's text and set the bounds
            let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObject(for: metadataObj)
            qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject!.bounds

            if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
                messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
                print(metadataObj.stringValue)
                found(code: metadataObj.stringValue)

            }
        }
    }

    func found(code: String) {
        print(code)
        /*
         Fire off the QR code to the database
        */
        let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
        client.delegate = client.self

    }
}
```

Comment: If you look at the sample on the link you provided, the code is `client.delegate = self`.  That should work, assuming that your class is updated to implement the `SQLClientDelegate ` protocol.

Comment: I've tried `client.delegate=self` too but no luck. I don't think my class has been updated to implement `SQLClientDelegate`. Would I do that in QRScannerController, make a new class, or by extending SQLClient?

Comment: If you're going to use `self` inside `QRScannerController` then that's where you would have to do it.  That's what `self` means: "this object".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being the part I was missing.

extension QRScannerController: SQLClientDelegate {
    func error(_ error: String!, code: Int32, severity: Int32) {
        print(error)
    }
}